# Divisibility issue

Tags: python, user-input, division

```
while True:
    value_1 = raw_input (" Please Enter the price in total cents or type 'done' to exit: ") 
    if value_1 == "done" :    
        print " Thank you,Good-Bye!"
        break
    else:
        value_1 = int(value_1)
        if value_1 % 5 == 0:
            continue  
        else:
            print "\n  Please Re-enter the Price in multiples of 5, Thank you!"
    if value_1 % 100 == 2 :
           print "x"
```

check for screen shot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIpjy.png)
If I enter a number multiple of 5
it should continue to run
but its going back again to top
or say if I enter 200 it should suppose to print `x`
but its doing nothing
its prompting again for user input

Comment: I actually want to enter "200" and print "x"

Comment: continue goes back to the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: Please describe what you actually intend to do and how it doesn't work.

Comment: The remainder of 200 divided by 100 is not 2, it is zero.

Comment: yeah that should not happen. or tell me what should i do to enter in to the last if loop

Comment: You wrote `value_1 % 100 == 2`, but for a `value_1 = 200`, that modulus result is going to be 0. If that modulus is actually supposed to be a division, then you should make that change.

Comment: @KishanJangam "yeah that should not happen". Then tell us what *should* happen!

Comment: @KishanJangam as per the program, if it doesn't equal "done" and any multiple of 5, the loop just continues and there is no way to get to your if statement at the end As per that, since all multiples of 200 or 100 constitute as multiple of 5, there is no way for you to test the divisibility

Comment: @idjaw i just want to enter in to the last if loop but the program is going back again to while loop.

Even if i write value_1 % 100 == 0, and enter 200 its not printing x

you said continue is going back to while loop. i dont want that. so how could i get the program enter the last loop

Comment: @HarshavardhanKonakanchi even if i enter a multiple of 5 its not entering in to the last if loop. Its re asking to enter the number again

Comment: @KishanJangam It will never enter.. cause you say that if it is divisible by 5, goto start of loop by using the continue statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you may have found out, the "continue" command doesn't make your code continue to the next step, but rather, it brings it back to the start of the loop. Thus, your code, if you enter a number that is divisible by 5, brings you back to the start of the loop and doesn't implement the second check.

The second problem is that, if I understand correctly that you want the script to print "x" if you enter 200, is that the second check

```
if value_1 % 100 == 2 :
```

checks if the remainder of the number if divided by 100 is 2. And, since before this check, you checked if the number was divisible by 5, you will never get the program to print "x". What you want is

```
if value_1 / 100 == 2
```

Additionally, to circumvent that "continue" problem, just nest the two checks like this

```
if value_1 % 5 == 0:
    if value_1 / 100 == 2 :
        print "x"  
    else:
        print "\n  Please Re-enter the Price in multiples of 5, Thank you!"
```

With this, if you type a multiple of 5, it brings you back to the prompt, and only if you type 200, it will print "x"

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as follows

```
while True:
    value_1 = raw_input (" Please Enter the price in total cents or type 'done' to exit: ") 
    if value_1 == "done" :    
        print " Thank you,Good-Bye!"
        break
    else:
        value_1 = int(value_1)
        if value_1 % 5 != 0:
            print "\n  Please Re-enter the Price in multiples of 5, Thank you!"
            continue
        if value_1 / 100 == 2 :
            print "x"
```

Comment: got it bro! Thank you!

Comment: bro

""print 'For a $',float(value_1)/100,'you need:' ""

I want a float output. for "float(value_1)/100"

It works fine if i enter 125 or 325 (1.25 and 3.25)but when i enter 350 its just giving me 3.5 as output. i need 3.50

What can i do? @harshavardhan konakanchi

Comment: @KishanJangam print ("%.2f" % (value_1/200) ) should work